# django template behaving odd, or is it?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a **class Explore**, which is used to get all the photos of other classes (like **Photo**, **ProfilePicture**, etc). And in the Explore class I have a method (`get_rendered_html`) which is used to render the objects in the template (`explore_photo.html`), so that I can pass it on to the main page (`index.html`).

**Update:**

Please let me elaborate my question. Suppose there are three Users **A**, **B** and **C**. If **A** is the current user, I want all the photos of **A** to be displayed, including other PUBLIC photos of **B** and **C**.

I tried this:

```
{% if object.display == 'P' or user == object.user %}
{% if object.display == 'P' or request.user == object.user %}
```

If I do it this way, only the public images are displayed, even though the current user is the object's user. And if I do this way:

```
{% if object.display == 'P' or user != object.user %}
```

All the image are displayed.

What may be the cause here? Please help me solve this problem. I would really appreciate your suggestion or advice. Thank you.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    ONLYME = 'O'
    FRIENDS = 'F'
    PUBLIC = 'P'
    CHOICES = (
        (ONLYME, "Me"),
        (FRIENDS, "Friends"),
        (PUBLIC, "Public"),
    )
    display = models.CharField(default='F', max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        verbose_name = 'photo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'photos'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description


class Explore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type','object_id')

    def get_rendered_html(self):
        template_name = 'explore_photo.html'
        return mark_safe(render_to_string(template_name, {'object': self.content_object}))
```

explore_photo.html:

```
{% if object.display == 'P' or user == object.user %}
<div class="explore_photo">
    <img src="media/{{ object.image }}">
    <p class="photo_date">{{ object.pub_date|date:"F jS Y, P" }}</p>
    <p class="photo_description">{{object.description}}</p>
    <p class="photo_user">{{ object.user }}</p>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

index.html:

```
<body>
    <h1>Explore</h1>
    <div id="explore">
        {% for photo in photos %}
            <p>1</p>
            {{ photo.get_rendered_html }}
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
```

**Update:**

```
def explore(request):
    """
    Return all the photos of the Explore Class in the Explore url
    """
    photos = Explore.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'photos':photos})
```

Comment: Can you add the view? Also, the filtering should be done in the view, not in the template.

Comment: @Nil I have updated the question. Please have a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with GenericForeignKey and I don't understand why you have a user FK in Explore. I'm sure of one thing though: the filtering should be done in the view, not in the template! Use a something like that:

```
photos = Explore.objects.filter(content_object__display='P',
                                content_object__user=request.user)

# But as I said, I don't understand this Explore model, so I would probably
# delete it and use Photo directly
photos = Photo.objects.filter(display='P', user=request.user)
```

Now you can remove the condition in your template and it should work.

**EDIT**

My bad, you need a OR query, not a AND. Use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) in the filter instead.

```
from django.db.models import Q

photos = Photo.objects.filter(Q(display='P') | Q(user=request.user))
# Idem for the Explore model or any other model where you need a OR or a
# complex query.
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't work for my needs. Please let me elaborate my question. Suppose there are three Users A,B,C. If A is the current user, I want all the photos of A to be displayed, including other PUBLIC photos of B and C. I have updated my question. Please have a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot it was a OR! I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to compare **User.pk** rather than **User objects**.

#### Edit :

In this line : `{% if object.display == 'P' or user == object.user %}` and the others involving user, object.user or request.user, django will not guarantee that the objects will be equal, even if they should be. To compare an object against another, you want to compare some values they hold, comparing primary keys (user.pk) is a convention.

`{% if object.display == 'P' or user.pk == object.user.pk %}` should work fine. (well, i honestly suppose it will)

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get you. Could please elaborate a little more. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for being too short on explanations, I edited my answer :)

Comment: I am sorry but it isn't working. Still only the public photos are displaying. Also I have edited my question. Please have a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, didn't see that one ! In Explore.get_rendered_html you don't pass a user item, nor a [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext). request.user or user won't be available. When in doubt, make the template renderer output debug information with the [{% debug %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) template tag. Anyway, you should prefer @Nil's answer which is "the right way" to do filtering, as mine is more focused on trying to explain (poorly, sorry for that) why your's didn't work.